# how does a pointer know its at the end of a heap memory?

Tags: c++

I am quite confused about how to go about the problem below any tip would be beneficial, thanks in advance!
For instance

`int * p = new int [5];`

if I choose not to use p[0] for initialization using a for loop that looks like

```
for(int i = 0; i< 5;i++){
   p[i] = i;
}
```

How can I initialize values in the block of memory on the heap using the dereference and increment operators? I don't think the code below is correct.

```
int val= 5 ;
for(; *p !=0; ++p){
 *p = ++val;  
}
```

Also using the same operator to print it out immediately after the assignments. My thought is that after initializing values in the heap memory, the position at which the pointer points to remains the same, so in order for me to start at the original position in the block of memory I would need to reset the location to where the pointer points -starting location in the block of memory- to print the contents in the block of memory on the heap.

Comment: The pointer doesn't know. You have to keep track by some other means.

Comment: Use a sentinel, the pointers don't "know" anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how does a pointer know its at the end of a heap memory?

A pointer is "dumb". It doesn't know such thing.

> How can I initialize values in the block of memory on the heap using the dereference and increment operators? I don't think the code below is correct.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int* it = p;
int* end = p + 5;
while(it != end){
    *it++ = ++val;  
}
```

P.S. Don't increment the pointer that owns the resource.

P.P.S. Avoid **owning** bare pointers.

P.P.P.S. Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Comment: thank you very much this is just what I needed.

Comment: "Avoid owning bare pointers." I would clarify it, there is nothing wrong with using raw pointers when ownership is not involved.

Comment: @Slava I added emphasis on owning.

Comment: On that subject: I suggest "Avoid bare _owning_ pointers".